# Rails transforming Query from Rails 3.2.12 to 4.0.0 Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I've got some problems convertigs Querys from My 3.2.12 Rails app to the new converted 4.2.0 version.

I got this:

```
@data[:weekday] ||= Xyz.count(:include => [:membership],
          :conditions => ["xyz.done_at IS NOT NULL AND xyz.course_id = ?", @course_id],
          :group => "WEEKDAY(xyz.done_at)").collect {| val | [val[0].to_i, val[1]]}
```

I've made this new one, is this the same?

```
@data[:weekday] = Xyz.where("done_at IS NOT NULL AND memberships.course_id = ?", @course_id).joins(:membership).group("WEEKDAY(done_at)").count()
```

And the I got this one:

```
@data[:xyz_per_hours] ||= Xyz.count(:include => [:membership],
           :conditions => ["xyz.done_at IS NOT NULL AND memberships.course_id = ?",  @course_id],
           :group => "TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, xyz.created_at, xyz.done_at)").to_a.select do | val |
  val[0].to_i < 120
end
```

I've converted it to:

```
@data[:xyz_per_hours] = Xyz.where("done_at IS NOT NULL AND course_id = ?",  @course_id).joins(:membership).group("TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, created_at, done_at)").count().to_a.select do | val |
    val[0].to_i < 120
  end
```

But I got this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, created_at, done_at) AS timestampdiff_hour_created_at_done_at FROM `xyz` INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `memberships`.`id` = `xyz`.`membership_id` WHERE (done_at IS NOT NULL AND course_id = 44) GROUP BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, created_at, done_at)
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In group clause

```
"TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, created_at, done_at)"
```

you need to specify a table for column `created_at` like it was in the original expression - `xyz.created_at`

And your first question

> I've made this new one, is this the same?

There is only one difference between both expressions - in the first one you use `:include => [:membership]` what means `LEFT OUTER JOINs` operation ([documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count)) but in the second one you use `joins(:membership)` which means `INNER JOIN` operation

Answer (score 1):

That last issue is occurring in your `#group` statement. Because youre joining on membership, and both membership and xyz have `created_at` attributes, the query doesnt know which `created_at` to order by.